# undefined symbol in shared library

Tags: linux, gcc, g++, shared-libraries

I compiled a shared library in linux. After the library is generated. I execute `ldd -r libfoo.so`. It come with **undefined symbol error**

my error message is as following

```
ldd -r libcaffe.so
   linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffdd541000)
   /opt/alisentry/$LIB/alisentry_connect.so =>         
   /opt/alisentry/lib64/alisentry_connect.so (0x00007ff8777bc000)
   /opt/alisentry/$LIB/alisentry_exec.so =>    
   /opt/alisentry/lib64/alisentry_exec.so (0x00007ff8775b8000)
   /opt/alisentry/$LIB/alisentry_kill.so => 
   ...
   libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff876291000)
   /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003671800000)
undefined symbol:  
       _ZN2cv12mulSpectrumsERKNS_11_InputArrayES2_RKNS_12_OutputArrayEi
       (./libcaffe.so)
undefined symbol: _ZN2cv17getOptimalDFTSizeEi    (./libcaffe.so)
undefined symbol: _ZN2cv3dftERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayEii    (./libcaffe.so)
```

**My question is that shared library have finished the compiling and linking. Why it still have undefined symbol, Why it not happen in linking stage**

Comment: Because of, probably, it needs another lib to be linked to as a pre-requisite.

Comment: If it need another lib. I think it should be generate errors while compiling

Answer (score 9):

Compile and link a shared library does not report, by default, undefined symbols.

They will be reported when you generates your executable file, where all symbols must be defined.

If you want to force [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc) to stop your lib build and gives you errors you have to enable **`--no-undefined`** option.

Comment: I think it is `-Wl,--no-undefined` as you are referring to `gcc`. `--no-undefined` holds true for `ld`however. Just to avoid confusion...

Comment: -Wl,--no-undefined does not seem to be able to properly handle weak symbols (visibility=hidden)